# HTML, JS: Scroll to div unreliable with collapsing navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm working on a website on which the navbar collapses and becomes opaque on scrolling down. This has caused an issue where clicking a link to a div down the page causes the top of that div to go to the top of the page, rather than underneath the bottom of the navbar. The website is live at [rewindrl.uk](http://rewindrl.uk). Is there some way to offset the div scrolling when at the top of the page so it lines up nicely, or otherwise 'predict' and factor in the height of the navbar when scrolled down?
The full source is at [github.com/rewindrl/rewindrl.github.io](https://github.com/rewindrl/rewindrl.github.io), as the website is hosted on GitHub Pages.

Navigation code:

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#tf-home" style="padding:0px"><img itemprop="image" src="/img/Rewind Transparent.png" width=50 height=50 alt="Rewind Gaming Logo"></img></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a href="#tf-home">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="/apply">Apply</a></li>
                <li><a href="/signup">Tournaments</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Navigation CSS:

```
#tf-menu {
margin-bottom: 0;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
color: #fff !important;
padding: 2% 0;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#tf-menu.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: #222222;
    padding: 1% 0;
}
#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #C5C5C5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #00D2FF;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Scrolling JS:

```
function main() {

(function () {
   'use strict';

   /*====================================
    Main Navigation Stick to Top when Scroll
    ======================================*/
    function sticky_relocate() {
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
      if (window_top > div_top) {
          $('#tf-menu').addClass('stick');
      } else {
          $('#tf-menu').removeClass('stick');
      }
  }

  $(function () {
      $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
      sticky_relocate();
  });


 $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
}());
}
main();
```

I don't have much experience with JS, and I'm using a CSS template, so please don't go too in-depth when explaining to me how stupid I am!
Thanks in advance,

bucketman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not try it, but I think it will help if you set `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70` to an higher value like `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 120`.

That `- 70` is the navigationbar. It´s already an offset of 70px

Try that ;)

Comment: Yeah, I managed to fix it by setting the offset to 175. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: That´s no Problem! :)